# How to get full end day on calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I have my events to display except that the event does not go until the end date, it stops 1 day before...
I tried with the `nextDayThreshold` and nothing, the format of my dates is as follows:
Y-m-d

any idea so that I can include the end date on the display of my events?

```
foreach ($dateEvent as $event) {
    $getDate = $this->wpBookingdatesRepository->findBy(['booking_id' => $event->getBookingId()]);

    if (count($getDate) === 2) {
        $dates[] = [
            "title" => "",
            "start" => $getDate[0]->getBookingDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
            "end" => $getDate[1]->getBookingDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
            "color" => "#f50202",
            "display" => "background"
        ];
    } elseif (count($getDate) === 1) {
        $dates[] = [
            "title" => "",
            "start" => $getDate[0]->getBookingDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
            "color" => "#f50202",
            "display" => "background"
        ];
    }
}
```

My api was generated with symfony in PHP

`events: 'devis/date/api',`

`ThresholdnextDay` and try to set date to format `Y-m-dTH:i:s`